# How to make a similar custom generator in Keras for a CNN that takes multiple images as inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am working on DR detection using CNNs on Google Colab. The CNN that I have designed has **3 inputs for 3 different grayscale images** of each eye (one original, one with extracted blood vessels, and one with extracted exudates). The code for the CNN is as follows:

```
#Custom CNN Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, concatenate
from keras.models import Sequential, Model

def cnn_model():
    input_1 = Input(shape=(224,224,1))
    input_2 = Input(shape=(224,224,1))
    input_3 = Input(shape=(224,224,1))

    b1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_1)
    b1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 1), activation='relu')(b1)
    b1 = Conv2D(8, (1, 3), activation='relu')(b1)
    b1 = BatchNormalization()(b1)
    b1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(b1)
    b1 = Dropout(0.25)(b1)
    b1 = Flatten()(b1)

    b2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 1), activation='relu')(input_2)
    b2 = Conv2D(4, (1, 3), activation='relu')(b2)
    b2 = BatchNormalization()(b2)
    b2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(b2)
    b2 = Dropout(0.25)(b2)
    b2 = Flatten()(b2)

    b3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 1), activation='relu')(input_3)
    b3 = Conv2D(4, (1, 3), activation='relu')(b3)
    b3 = BatchNormalization()(b3)
    b3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(b3)
    b3 = Dropout(0.25)(b3)
    b3 = Flatten()(b3)

    concatenated = concatenate([b1, b2, b3])

    fc = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(concatenated)
    fc = Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(fc)
    fc = Dense(units=16, activation='relu')(fc)

    op = Dense(units=5, activation='softmax')(fc)

    final = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2, input_3], outputs=[op])

    final.compile( optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])  #define optimizer and loss functions as well as required metrics
   
    final.summary()

    return final
```

The block-diagram of the proposed architecture (with 3 branches) is shown below:

[proposed-cnn-architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFQui.png)

Since using the default *ImageDataGenerator* provided by Keras causes Colab to crash, probably because of very large number of images (~35,000 images of high resolution), I have written my own Custom Data Generator that uses the **numpy arrays of only the filenames of the images** in one batch at a time, rather than the actual images themselves, and thus preventing the crashing of Colab (that's what I believe), the code for which is as follows:

```
class Custom_Generator(keras.utils.Sequence) :

  #constructor for initializing class instance
  def __init__(self, image_filenames, labels, batch_size) :
    self.image_filenames = image_filenames
    self.labels = labels
    self.batch_size = batch_size

  #num of batches    
  def __len__(self) :
    return (np.ceil(len(self.image_filenames) / float(self.batch_size))).astype(np.int)
  
  #function that delivers the batches to the model
  def __getitem__(self, idx) :

    #creating each batch for image filenames as well as labels on the basis of its index
    batch_x = self.image_filenames[idx * self.batch_size : (idx+1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size : (idx+1) * self.batch_size]

    img_list = []

    for file_name in batch_x:
      orig_img = cv2.imread("../resized_train_cropped/" + str(file_name))
      
      blood_ves, exu = preprocess_image(orig_img)
      
      #resizing all images to 224*224
      blood_ves = cv2.resize(blood_ves, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
      exu = cv2.resize(exu, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
      orig_img = cv2.resize(orig_img, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

      orig_img = cv2.cvtColor(orig_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

      #normalizing all pixel values
      blood_ves = blood_ves / 255.0
      exu = exu / 255.0
      orig_img = orig_img / 255.0

      #temporary list to hold all 3 images
      temp_list = []
      temp_list.append(orig_img)
      temp_list.append(blood_ves)
      temp_list.append(exu)

      #converting temp_list to a numpy array
      temp_list = np.array(temp_list)

      img_list.append(temp_list) 
    
    #returning the resized images of a batch and their respective labels as numpy arrays
    return np.array(img_list), np.array(batch_y)
```

The code for implementing the model:

```
model = cnn_model()

#Preparing for saving the model at each checkpoint

checkpoint_path = "cp_cust.ckpt"

#save model after every 10 batches
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, 
                                                 verbose=1, 
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 save_freq=10)

train_len = X_data_bal.shape[0]

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  history = model.fit_generator(generator=training_batch_generator,
                                steps_per_epoch = int(train_len // batch_size),
                                epochs = 10,
                                verbose = 1,
                                callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

The same data generator had earlier worked for single input images, but now throws the following list of errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1844: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-caf54c85826b> in <module>()
      4                                 epochs = 10,
      5                                 verbose = 1,
----> 6                                 callbacks=[cp_callback])

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1859         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1860         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1861         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1862 
   1863   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1062           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1063           model=self,
-> 1064           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1065 
   1066       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1110         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1111         distribution_strategy=ds_context.get_strategy(),
-> 1112         model=model)
   1113 
   1114     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    907         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    908         model=model,
--> 909         **kwargs)
    910 
    911   @staticmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    779     peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
    780     peek = self._standardize_batch(peek)
--> 781     peek = _process_tensorlike(peek)
    782 
    783     # Need to build the Model on concrete input shapes.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _process_tensorlike(inputs)
   1014     return x
   1015 
-> 1016   inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_numpy_and_scipy, inputs)
   1017   return nest.list_to_tuple(inputs)
   1018 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    657 
    658   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    661 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    657 
    658   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    661 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _convert_numpy_and_scipy(x)
   1009       if issubclass(x.dtype.type, np.floating):
   1010         dtype = backend.floatx()
-> 1011       return ops.convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(x, dtype=dtype)
   1012     elif scipy_sparse and scipy_sparse.issparse(x):
   1013       return _scipy_sparse_to_sparse_tensor(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1403   
   1404   return convert_to_tensor_v2(
-> 1405       value, dtype=dtype, dtype_hint=dtype_hint, name=name)
   1406 
   1407 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1413       name=name,
   1414       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1415       as_ref=False)
   1416 
   1417 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1538 
   1539     if ret is None:
-> 1540       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1541 
   1542     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    263   
    264   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 265                         allow_broadcast=True)
    266 
    267 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    274       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    275         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 276     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    277 
    278   g = ops.get_default_graph()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    299 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    300   """Implementation of eager constant."""
--> 301   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    302   if shape is None:
    303     return t

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Edit 1:

I had used ImageDataGenerator for batches of only a single input image (batch size of 256) as given below. I had used *Flow* method on numpy arrays of resized images (224, 224, 3) to instantiate the generators. However, it always gave an error of "Session Crashed" or "Google Drive Error" after 5-10 mins. So, I used the Custom Generator with same batch size and it worked:

```
#loading the numpy arrays of images and labels
X_data = np.load(r'Data\X_data.npy')
y_data = np.load(r'Data\y_data.npy')

#creating training, cross-validation, and testing sets
X_train, X_new, y_train, y_new = ms.train_test_split(X_data, y_data, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
X_crossval, X_test, y_crossval, y_test = ms.train_test_split(X_new, y_new, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 0)

#training and testing data generators (No Augmentation initially)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(X_train,
                                     y_train,
                                     batch_size = 256)

val_generator = test_datagen.flow(X_crossval,
                                  y_crossval,
                                  batch_size = 256)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow(X_test,
                                   y_test,
                                   batch_size = 256)

model = cnn_model()

#training the model
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // 256,
                              epochs = 10,
                              validation_data = val_generator)
```

The CNN was based on Inception-v3, with only a single input image:

```
#inception v3 CNN model

#importing required libraries
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, TensorBoard
from keras import optimizers, losses, activations, models
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Dense, Input, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Concatenate
from keras import applications

def cnn_model():

  #initializing base model to build upon
  base_model = applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', 
                                  include_top=False, 
                                  input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
  
  #freezing the weights of base model 
  base_model.trainable = False

  add_model = Sequential()
  add_model.add(base_model)

  #Adding layers on Base Model
  add_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D()) #average pooling to reduce dims until 1
  add_model.add(Dropout(0.5)) #dropping nodes for regularization
  add_model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax')) #5 output neurons

  model = add_model

  #compiling the new model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, 
                momentum=0.9),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  
  model.summary()

  return model
```

Basically, I had used a model based on Inception-v3, just to observe the benefits of transfer learning. However, now I am working on a custom model that can take 3 input images.

Comment: change the batch size to 32 and steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) // 32. Your batch size is to large.

Answer (score 0):

you say the ImageDataGenerator causes Colab to crash. Please show the code you used for this. Did you use .flow_from_directory? If so what is the setting for the batch_size? If this is set with to large a value it may cause use of two much memory especially if you have 3  generators running. The fact that you have 35,000 images should not be a factor if you are retrieving the images in batches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding Sir. I have included all the relevant code in Edit 1. Please let me know how I can handle the crashing and multiple input images using ImageDataGenerator.

Comment: In your custom_generator class  you have the code  blood_ves, exu = preprocess_image(orig_img). I assume the code creates the two additional images, is that correct?

Comment: Yes Sir. So 3 grayscale images in total, the original, the blood vessels, and the exudates